# Getting nearest Hospital information by using MapQuest API

Tags: api, mapquest

How to get a list of hospital details (with address) near by customer address using MapQuest?

For example my address is : 1015 museum circle jacksonville FL

Using 5-box address format KVP Request, I got 
[Lat,Long](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=KEY_HERE&street=1015%20museum%20circle&city=jacksonville&state=FL&postalCode=32207)
("lat":30.318548,"lng":-81.659093)

How to format the MapQuest or Nominatim URL request to get hospital list near by customer address?

Keyword to search : Hospital Or Clinic

Radius : 50 miles or 100 miles

Answer (score 2):

30 mile search around the address, max results of 25

- you can either skip the geocode and use the address for the origin, and it will geocode on the fly (ambiguities=ignore means it will take the best geocode result as the origin), or use the lat,lng as the origin

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>&origin=1015%20museum%20circle%20jacksonville%20FL&radius=30&hostedData=mqap.ntpois%7Cgroup_sic_code=?%7C806202&maxMatches=25&r&ambiguities=ignore
```

Documentation here:
http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/radius-search.html

Comment: Is it possible to search by keyword e.g. "gas station" instead of the sic_code?

Comment: found the answer: https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=KEY&origin=Denver, CO&maxMatches=10&radius=5&ambiguities=ignore&hostedData=mqap.ntpois|name ILIKE ?|%coffee%